# Difference between mysqli_fetch_object and $res->fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i don´t understand what is the difference between:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)
```

and this:

```
$row = $res->fetch_object()
```

And which one is better.

Comment: one's procedural, the other's OOP. as for better, that's completely an opinion, and opinions are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B pointed out in the comments, one is Object Oriented and the other one is procedural.
Which one is better is completely up to you and your use case. Just use which one feels more comfortable to you.

Details can be found on the Documentation for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).